# How to test if the first character of each word in a list is a vowel, then print it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing GrokLearning NCSS Challenge Intermediate level and I'm wondering how to find out if the first character of each word in a list is a vowel, if it is then print it?

I've done this so far...

```py
printing_words = []
word = input("Words: ")
b = word.split()
for w in b:
  if w[0] == "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u":
    printing_words.append(w)
print(printing_words)
```

I expect an output of:

```py
Words: ham ant egg apple banana
ant apple egg
```

In alphabetical order and all that

Help please?

Comment: `if w[0] == "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u"` is a common gotcha (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value) and will always return `True`.... you'll be closer to what you want if you do `if w[0] in 'aeiou'` instead...

Comment: You teeter on the edge of contravening the 'homework help' rules on SO (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Grok has specialist tutors that can help you, available directly on their site. They'll give you better quality help, and are almost certainly speedier with their responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `in` instead of `or`.

```
words = input("Words: ")

printing_words = list()
for word in words.split():
    if word[0] in 'aeiou':
        printing_words.append(word)

# sorting words in alphabetical order while removing brackets as it prints
print(*sorted(printing_words))
```

Answer (score 0):

`str`s have method called `startswith` which accept `tuple` of allowed starts (*prefixes*), so you might use it following way:

```
if w.startswith(("a","e","i","o","u")):
```

Note that you might feed `startswith` with `tuple` of different-length `str`s.

Comment: or `if w[0] in ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")`

Answer (score 0):

you can filter the words from your words list by checking if each lowered word
starts with a vowel than you can sort them alphabetically:

```
sentence = input("Words: ")
words = sentence.split()

vowel = ("a","e","i","o","u")
print_words = sorted(filter(lambda w: w.lower().startswith(vowel), words))
print(*print_words)
```

output:

```
Words: ham ant egg apple banana
ant apple egg
```

Comment: `print(*print_words)` adding asterisk before list inside `print()` is more convenient than using `join()`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
printing_words = []
theWord = input("Words: ")
b = theWord.split()
for w in b:
   printing_words.append(w)
words_starting_with_vowel = [word for word in printing_words if word[0] in 'aeiou']
words_starting_with_vowel.sort();
print(words_starting_with_vowel);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not helpful. How does this code help solve the question asked? What is it doing?

Comment: @GoatsWearHats What this code is doing is exactly what the question asked. It finds any words the user inputs that start with a vowel and then outputs a list of the words in alphabetical order. Why are you troubled with this code? Code-only answers are just as fine as regular answers.

Answer (score -1):

```
word = input("Words: ")
printing_words = sorted([w for w in word.split() if w[0] in "aeiou"])
print(printing_words)
```

```
Words: ham ant egg apple banana
['ant', 'apple', 'egg']
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not helpful. What is your code doing? Why is it useful in providing a solution to this question?